# Strange vertical space before the caption of a longtable with KOMA-Script classes when xcolor is loaded

Tags: spacing, color, captions, koma-script, longtable

When using one of the main KOMA-Script classes — `scrartcl`, `scrreprt`, `scrbook` but not `scrlttr2` —, the vertical position of the caption in a `longtable` environment changes when one loads or unloads the `xcolor` package: if the latter is loaded, there is an additional spacing above the caption.

Here is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}% scrartcl, scrreprt, scrbook

\usepackage{xcolor}% comment and uncomment to see the effect
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
%
\noindent%
\centering%
Blah blah blah blah.
\begin{longtable}{l l l l}
\hline
\caption{Caption} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
\endfoot
Cell & Cell & Cell & Cell \\
Cell & Cell & Cell & Cell \\
\end{longtable}
Blah blah blah blah.
%
\end{document}
```

The result is given in the following picture.

[image: Caption spacing in longtable whether xcolor is loaded or not]

The problem also happens if I load `xcolor` after `longtable` or if I put the caption at the foot of the table. **But**, if I load the `caption` package, the additional space disappears and the result is the first — expected — one in every case. I just don’t need this additional package, provided that I can get what I want with the commands and options from the KOMA-Script classes. Finally, there is no such situation with the standard classes, whether the package `caption` is loaded or not.

(Just a few remarks about my code: I have only inserted the `\hline` before the caption to make the situation clearer, and the problem still occurs without it; furthermore, in a final version, I would obviously use `\captionabove` instead of `\caption` or the KOMA-Script option `captions=tableheading`, as well as `booktabs`!)

The question is: how do I get rid of the additional space without loading the `caption` package?

I have a subsidiary question: why is the spacing after the `longtable` environment greater than the spacing before? By default, both lengths `\LTpre` and `\LTpost` are defined as equal to `\bigskipamount`, in the `longtable` package.

Comment: This seems a bug in the KOMA-Script classes. It doesn't happen with `article`. With `scrartcl` there is an additional space anyway.

Comment: You should contact Markus Kohm or file a bug report at http://www.komascript.de/ or http://developer.berlios.de/projects/koma-script3/

Comment: @cgnieder I reported the bug: https://developer.berlios.de/bugs/?func=detailbug&bug_id=19020&group_id=4307. For the time being, I will use the `caption` package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A workaround without loading any extra packages is

```
\def\capfont{\leavevmode\normalfont\normalcolor}
```

which adds `\leavevmode`